# Can't open Custom Post Types Link in navigation

Tags: custom-post-types, css

I have a problem with the archives permalinks of custom post types: They won't open by clicking on the links in the header navigation.

I am able to open the link directly in the browser by typing the url duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemchecks. The page uses my template called archives-customposttype.php.

But the link doesn't open, when I click on it in the header navigation that also uses the direct link duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemchecks.

I am not sure if it is a problem with wordpress or my own html/css style. What could be important is that I am using a z-index on the navigation area.

I appreciate any help!

Here is the code: The Navigation has to parts. 
1) A horizontal menu when entering the page
2) A fixed menu that appears after a certain amount of scrolled pixels

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-links pull-right">
         <?php //wp_nav_menu(); ?>
        <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemchecks/">Parfümchecks</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemwissen/">Parfümwissen</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/ueber-duftfaktor/">Über Duftfaktor</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="icon-facebook icon-large" alt="Facebook"></i></a></li>
       <li> <a href=""><i class="icon-twitter icon-large"></i></a></li>
       <li><?php get_search_form(); ?></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav><!--/.navbar -->


<!-- Fixed navbar - unten-->
```

```
        </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-links pull-right" id="fixednav">
        <?php //wp_nav_menu(); ?> 
     <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemchecks/">Parfümchecks</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/parfuemwissen/">Parfümwissen</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://duftfaktor.de/wp/ueber-duftfaktor/">Über Duftfaktor</a></li>
       <li> <a href=""><i class="icon-facebook icon-large" alt="Facebook"></i></a></li>
       <li> <a href=""><i class="icon-twitter icon-large"></i></a></li>
       <li><?php get_search_form(); ?></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you made the menu? Do you just print out the links? Is it static or do you use some functionality provided by WordPress? Your blog is not accessible so it's quite impossible to make a bet.

Comment: The menu is static, wrapped in <ul> and <li>. I added the code above.

Comment: if you think it's css related, use your browser's inspector to check the stack order of elements. no one will be able to give you more than a guess with the the information you've provided, we'd need to see it in context, and your site is password protected.

Comment: the password is "schnueffeln"

Comment: it works if I disable javascript, you have some javascript code somewhere that's trapping clicks on your nav and preventing default behavior. this is likely an issue specific to your theme and not something in WordPress core.

Comment: I'm seeing a whole series of 404 errors for sticky.js in devtools, which I'm guessing is related to the sticky header you're trying to build. Seconding Milo's suggestion that your problem is likely with the js in your theme.